# Problemas com requisição ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

Bom, estou tentando realizar uma simples requisição ajax, porém o conteúdo chamado não está sendo exibido. Como posso resolver ?

```
var xmlhttp;

function callContent(){

    var mainContent = document.querySelector(".main-content");
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "random.php", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callback(mainContent);

    xmlhttp.send();

}

function callback(contentDiv){
    console.log(xmlhttp);
    if(xmlhttp.readystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){

        contentDiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

    }

}
```

Comment: Esse console.log está mostrando o conteúdo corretamente?

Comment: também não, mas quando abro o random.php ele funciona perfeitamente. o status do readystatechange ficam em 0, mesmo solicitando o open e send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Murilo, muda essa linha  xmlhttp.open("GET", "random.php", true); para  xmlhttp.open("GET", "random.php", false);, neste caso você está dizendo que a chamada será síncrona e você vai conseguir debugar e ver o retorno da sua chamada.

Comment: não ocorreu nada de diferente, só no console que apareceu um aviso dizendo que não se deve usar XMLHttp síncrono na thread principal

Comment: o arquivo continua sendo solicitado, mas não é exibido.

Comment: Fiz alguns console.log's, o readystate dele fica em null sempre que a requisição é feita

Comment: em readystate, basta colocar o S em maíusculo ... :/